# Can you open a ServerSocket from Tomcat on Startup?

Tags: java, sockets, tomcat

I need to stream binary data in real time through a socket from Tomcat.

Can you open a `ServerSocket` on Tomcat at startup? If so, where do you do that?

Comment: You need it when starting Tomcat or when deploying your web application?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis OP's question title differs greatly from content =\

Comment: When you mean at startup, you mean when deploying the web application, right?

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza Right, when deploying the web application.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis A Java client that needs streaming data will make a socket connection.

Comment: I cannot see a good reason to use Tomcat for this when it provides no benefit and incurs substantial overhead versus a standalone java application.  I think the real question is why the OP feels they need a ServerSocket in their Tomcat instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html), more specifically, in the [`contextInitialized`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized%28javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent%29) method.

Basic example:

```
public class ApplicationListener implements ServletContextListener {
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
         //handle the server socket connection here...
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
    }
}
```

Note that if `contextInitialized` method throws any `Exception`, the web application won't deploy at all.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Define a servlet that Tomcat starts on application startup. When the servlet is loaded create a thread to open the ServerSocket.

I have done this in the past so that I could use Tomcat's infrastructure to create a custom TCP/IP server process. I also created a set of JSP pages for managing the application that was exposing the socket.

Comment: This is not recommended. That's not a job for a servlet.

Comment: Worked very well for me. Been in production without issue since 2007:)

Comment: Sorry. I work in business. That fact that it works is all that matters. Ivory tower considerations don't play in my company.

Comment: I work in business too. Probably that marks the difference: people that make things work and people that make it work right and efficiently.

Comment: @corwin766g A [`Servlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html) is a _small Java program that runs within a Web server. Servlets receive and respond to requests from Web clients_. It is not well suited for setting up `ServerSocket`s for parallel operation.

Comment: Correction: A servlet is a Java class - it is not a program. It runs within a Servlet container - usually a HTTP server - not always. Could also be a MQ server. We've done that too. Or a custom TCP/IP server.

Comment: @corwin766g Notice I linked and quoted the official Oracle documentation. My point was that the responsibility of a `Servlet` is to respond to requests.

Comment: @Luiggi. We have people that waste time on making things "work right". We call them recent college graduates. I used to be one of those people. Since this solution worked perfectly for us - no crashes, no support issues, no ongoing maintenance - it is a correct design *FOR US*. Don't downvote unless you can provide concrete evidence the solution will not work. You provided only attitude and rudeness.

Comment: I downvoted because me in previously works tested both `ServletContextListener` and using a plain `Servlet` for this and while both did the work nice and well the design rules should be on the `ServletContextListener`. It wasn't an academic project nor nothing that you said in previous comments. And yes, if it is about making it work and making it work right in the same amount of time, I will **always** prefer the latter.

Comment: By the way, I've already faced this situation about *it works, keep it like that*. I do not tend to do premature optimization either, but having the right design from the start prevents situations like *hey, production environment is going down! Start profiling to see why it works but dies*.